# Create Dynamic Web Service Client in Eclipse using "Web Service Client Wizard"

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

Created a Web Service Client in Eclipse using "Web Service Client Wizard" listed in following link which worked great with a single proxy / URI.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf

However, how can we adjust the system to create a dynamic proxy (Same application or web service client functions but in different servers). Is there any wizard to do it? If not, how can it be done?

Thanks